# Unable to set Horizontal Scroll GridView at bottom of layout (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I am using Horizontal Scroll for GridView items, and its working fine but its showing the list of images at the top of layout so i want to to show the GridView List at the bottom of layout :

**Main layout :**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/ImageViewGrid"
            android:layout_width="4000dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"></GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: use recyclerview instead with horizontal flag.

Comment: can i get an example please

Answer (score 0):

Just use `RecyclerView` for all your above layout and use a `GridLayoutManager` with  horizontal orientation. There is no  need of `HorizontalScrollView` when using `RecyclerView` for your case.